# Add existing Poetry venv to pyenv virtualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

How do I add an existing Poetry venv to Pyenv so that I see it when I run `pyenv virtualenvs`?

I created a Poetry venv with command - `poetry shell`

Poetry venv - `$HOME/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/py3.11`

When I run `pyenv virtualenvs` I only see my previous environment:

`py3.9.16 --> $HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/envs/py3.9.16`

I have the following installed:

```
pyenv 2.3.17
virtualenv 20.23.1
pyenv-virtualenv 1.2.1
Poetry (version 1.5.1)
```